# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm pretty new to JavaScript/JQuery and am getting an error that I've not been able to find a resolution for.  What I'm trying to do is use JQuery to callapse (accordion) any elements on my page with a class of .question.  The error I'm getting though actually seems to be on the $(function(){ line instead of the accordion line!  Please helped, I'm totally stumped!

```
<head>
    <title>GfG</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script src="js/QfG.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/QfG/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="QfG.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css">
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".question").accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>
</head>
```

The error is happening on $(function() { ... at least according to the Chrome dev tools...

Comment: maybe the path to `js/jquery-1.10.2.js` is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your custom jQuery UI build actually contains the accordion component?

Comment: @user2803020 go to console tab of inspector and type `$` then hit `enter`, what does it returns? if function then you jquery loaded if undefined then surely you have a path issue.

Comment: What does `QfG.js` do? Does your custom jQueryUI build include the `accordion` method?

Comment: I used the console and entered $ and was given the following: function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)}

I've also checked all the .js files and find that the accordion is in jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js, but that's the only place.

I removed the reference to js/QfG.js and have the smae results.

I'm wondering if this is because I'm trying to use accordion on a class instead of an ID?

Comment: I also changed my script to read as this:

    <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.question').accordion({
       collapsible: true
     });
   });
</script>

After doing that in now says the error is on $('.question').accordion({

Answer (score 2):

After load the page in google chrome do these stuffs. 
- Right click on page 
- Go to 'console' option 
- Here you will get all the errors if server is not responding or file paths are wrong. 
- Give proper paths of all js 
- That's all.!

Answer (score 0):

it seems, that your relative file-path to `js/jquery-1.10.2.js` is wrong, because `undefined is not a function` means, that `$` is undefined. `$` Itself is a jQuery Object, pointing to a "constructor" function.

Answer (score 0):

It actually turns out the error was occurring because I was using Chromium instead of Chrome.  Ooops...  Works fine in FireFox and Chrome, apparently Chromium doesn't like jQuery.

Sooo...the "I'm a bonehead" solution seems to be applicable here.

Answer (score -3):

Adding the HTML that matches the jQuery selector should help, for example: `<div class="question"></div>`